# How to include excel chart in mail merge

Tags: email, charts, merge

just i want **include chart** from excel to **mail merge**(ms word).i can include any fields from excel but i cant add chart to the mail merge.How that can be done Is any other possible ways.

Answer (score 0):

Embed or link the Excel chart in the Word merge document as you would in a normal Word file, e.g. copy the Excel chart, and paste it into Word as an object, image or link. The place your mail merge fields as desired and complete the merge.